# Prefix Django base URL pattern

Tags: python, django, url, webcal

My service implemented in Django is hosting iCal calendar files. I want this files to be opened as a webcal stream, but this requires URL to be composed in a certain way so that browser/system/another service understands what should it do to handle this file properly. The URL should look like this: `webcal://myservice.com/icalfile`, but the URL pattern in Django starts only at `myservice.com` base url, for example:

```
url(r'^/icalfile$', views.ReturnICS.as_view())
```

is the equivalent of:

```
myservice.com/icalfile
```

Although I can explicitly insert `webcal://` to a url for each ical file represented in a template and pass it as variable when rendering view, like this for instance:

```
ics_url = 'webcal://' + icalfileurl
```

**I'd very much like to find a way to compose a full url pattern** that already has 'webcal://' part included, something like:

```
url(r'webcal://^*/icalfile$', views.ReturnICS.as_view())
```

* – is where base URL is.
but Django does not recognise this construction.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. `webcal` is the protocol, it's not something that would be caught by Django's URL dispatcher.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for a good point, so you think it's a better practice to just adds static "webcal://" to a url and pass it as variable to template?